# How to retrieve SHA1 of a file from the ObjectDatabase

Tags: libgit2sharp

I've checked the source code but couldn't find a method to retrieve SHA1 of a file from the ObjectDatabase by its path.

It's easy to calculate SHA1 manually but it requires reading a file which might cause performance issues.

Comment: If your file has changes staged, do you want the version of the file in `HEAD`, or in the index?

Comment: @EdwardThomson sorry for not to be clear. I want the version in the HEAD or from any commit in the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your file has been previously committed:**

```
Commit commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commitSha);

// Or if it's just been committed
// Commit commit = repo.head.Tip;

string shaFromKnownCommit = commit["path/to/file.txt"].Target.Id.Sha;
```

**If your file has only been staged (promoted to the staging area):**

```
string shaFromStagedFile = repo.Index["path/to/file.txt"].Id.Sha;
```

Comment: Thanks! So in order to get the SHA1 of a previously committed file I need to know the commit's SHA1, the path is not enough? I was trying to look up in commits like repo.Commits.Where(c => c[relativePath] != null) but it returns commits for other files too.

Comment: A Commit is a snapshot of your whole source code at a certain moment in time. Once you commit a file, it will exists in every following commit. Unless you remove the file from your working directory, stage the removal and commit the change.